# Unity How to make GameObject Speed gain velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a Torpedo in a Unity3D game that I'm making in Unity3D and I have a Torpedo fire out of a sub. How can I make the Torpedo fire like a Torpedo (start really slow) and then gain lots of momentum and speed up, like in movies.

Below is my code for how I'm doing this, but it doesn't work very well.

```
    float torpedoSpeed = (0.00001f) * 155.2f;

   //move
    gameObject.transform.position += new Vector3(velocity, 0, 0) * 15.5f;
```

Comment: What does "doesn´t work very well" mean for you? Does it get faster or not?

Comment: Make the torpedo be dependent on a time variable, which naturally will increase the more time has passed. The same way the speed of the object will too.

Comment: Aw, awesome! That does the trick!        gameObject.transform.position += new Vector3(velocity * timeLiving, 0, 0) * 5.5f; (this is the fix)

Comment: you might want to use Time.deltaTime instead of timeliving to make it go smoother, also for your next question please use the tag unity3d. This is not unity you are talking about ( yes there is a difference )

Comment: you might want to set max speed as torpedo also can't pass certain speed

Comment: Aw thanks for the feedback guys! Ill try and mess around with these tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern torpedo can actually speed up because they are propelled. Therefore the trick is to accelerate the torpedo.

Acceleration requires a Force in a direction. You must first determine the mass of the torpedo, which will allow you to apply a Force to it so that it accelerates.

[image]

So acceleration is the Force applied divided by the mass of the object.

---

That being said, you can add force to an object in Unity by simply using:

```
gameObject.rigidbody.mass = 0.5;

gameObject.rigidbody.AddForce(100, 0, 0);
```

Or you can add a constant force that will keep the torpedo always accelerating.

```
gameObject.constantForce.relativeForce = Vector3(0, 0, 1);
```